Using overloads to distribute work based on generic type
I have a class that stores 3 queues, and needs to be able to add an event of a given type to the appropriate queue:
class MyClass{
  Queue<Event<Person>> _personQueue;
  Queue<Event<Place>> _placeQueue;
  Queue<Event<Thing>> _thingQueue;

  public void AddEvent<T>(Event<T> evt) where T : class, INoun {
    // do stuff
  }
}

There's a couple options for do stuff.  The most obvious is to check the type of the generic argument at runtime
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Person)) {
  _personQueue.Enqueue((Event<Person>) evt);
} else if //...

however, this question recommends overloaded methods. I attempted this like this
public void AddEvent<T>(Event<T> evt) where T : class, INoun {
  OverloadedAddEvent(evt);
}

private void OverloadedAddEvent(Event<Person> person) { _personQueue.Enqueue(person); }
private void OverloadedAddEvent(Event<Place> place) { _placeQueue.Enqueue(place); }
private void OverloadedAddEvent(Event<Thing> thing) { _thingQueue.Enqueue(thing); }

but this does not compile, presumably because it's possible that the generic argument <T> could be an implementation of INoun that isn't Person, Place, or Thing, and I have not provided a method for such a case?
I can get it to compile by changing the argument of AddEvent to dynamic, but I'm not sure that's what I want to do here.
How do I get this to work? Is there a constraint I can add to clarify that the generic argument will always be one of these 3 classes? Is the compiler failing for some other reason?

I think you misunderstood the answer you linked. The point of that answer is that you should not have a generic method. Just write 3 public overloads.

If you need runtime dispatch (because overloads are statically-dispatched) you can add an enum property to your INoun that indicates which queue it should be dropped into. A switch over a trivial enum property will be significantly faster than runtime type-checks (e.g. if( foo.GetType() == typeof(TSomething) , or typeof(T) == typeof(Person) - neither are something you should be doing (for reasons I won't go into, unless you want to learn all the gotchas in Type.IsAssignableFrom or Type.IsAssignableTo or Type.IsInstanceOfType  - none of which are high-performance.

@Dai How would I create such an enum? Can you post an answer elaborating on your suggestion?

@ewok Sweeper's comment is the way to go. Just rename your three overloads to AddEvent and make them public. That's all there's to it.

@ewok I would, but what I proposed wouldn't be a good solution because I feel the 3 overloads is the simplest and best approach. (Also I have a meeting in a few minutes)
